# Can I find if any instance of my dialog is running?

Tags: android, android-activity, instance

I have a custom dialog as a custom message box. When I start it, I want to know if any instance of it is running or not.

How can I do that?

Comment: It's very difficult to answer a question like this without any more context. Posting the code that creates and shows the message box would be nice, as would telling us what GUI framework you're using, how the message box is created, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set boolean flag.

```
public static boolean isDialogrunning=false;
public static Dialog dialog;

like_
dialog=new Dialog(..);
 dialog.show();
isDialogrunning=true;


.......
.....
if(isDialogrunning)
{
    dialog.dismiss();
   isDialogrunning=false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create static instance of your dialog. and check whether the instance is null or not to knoe whether the dialog is running or not